# Mongo query in Spring's @Query annotation does not exclude fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-repositories

I wish to retrieve only selective data from Mongo document. I specified the fields that are not required in my @Query annotation. But it still retrieves the same.

```
@Repository
public interface PartnerPageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Partner, Long>, MongoRepository<Partner, Long> {    

 @Query(value = "{ 'name' : { $regex : ?0 , $options : 'i' } }", fields = "{ serviceCharge : 0 }")
 public Page<Partner> findAllByName(String name, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Despite the tag, 'serviceCharge' and 'charges' fields are still being fetched along with their corresponding data.

Is it because of any relation with Page interface or am I doing something wrong ?

**Edit**
Here is the Partner class :

```
@Data
@ToString(includeFieldNames = true)
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = false)
@Document(collection = "partner")
public class Partner extends AuditCommonBaseModel{

  @Id
  String _id;

  String name;

  String url;

  String email;

  String phone;

  Payment payment;

  ServiceCharge serviceCharge;

}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. Kindly elaborate

Comment: can you show how your Partner class look like

Comment: Yes I have added the same in question details

Comment: is your query running properly?  I mean with regex and case insensitivity?

Comment: Yes my friend. double checked in Robo Mongo